# ComboBox with CheckBoxes in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, drop-down-menu, windows-controls

I am trying to implement a CheckBox ComboBox. I followed this link as a reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown?msg=4152597#xx4152597xx

But there are some problems with this example.

1) After the drop-down list is shown, the very first mouse single-click to change the selected item's check-status always fails to do so, but succeeding single-clicks are fine. It seems the very first single-click is swallowed. I did some trace works but failed to find an answer.

2) The form loses focus when the list opens.

Comment: Check out the following question.  [Is there a simple way to implement a checked combobox in winforms?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822678/is-there-a-simple-way-to-implement-a-checked-combobox-in-winforms/8823170#8823170

Comment: I tried that example looks very good but only one fault is that, I am not able to keep dropdrop open till I finish all my selection. Do you know how can I keep it open? I am trying to catch WndProc Msg. But I coudnt find any success yet.

Comment: I did a `comboBox.ShowDropDown()` in the clickEvent and worked.