# Combobox closes before i can select a checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mmc3

I'm currently working in VS 2012.
.NET 4.5 and working on an mmc snap-in. (i know right?!)

so i followed this topic:

[Is there a simple way to implement a Checked Combobox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822678/is-there-a-simple-way-to-implement-a-checked-combobox-in-winforms)

as i want something similar to the scheduled task manager.

But that solution does not seem to work for me.
the listview pops up but when i try to click on a checkbox in my listview.
It gives me a big middle finger and closes my dropdown.

is there any way i can suppress the combobox's "focus lost"  close event?
i can, not hide the list but then it never hides.

For Example:

```
// designer class


// 
// comboBox1
// 
this.comboBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.comboBox1.DropDownHeight = 1;
this.comboBox1.DropDownWidth = 1;
this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.comboBox1.IntegralHeight = false;
this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(256, 371);
this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(238, 21);
this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 5;
this.comboBox1.DropDown += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_DropDown);
this.comboBox1.DropDownClosed += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_DropDownClosed);
// 
// lstWeekDays
// 
this.lstWeekDays.CheckBoxes = true;
this.lstWeekDays.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 63);
this.lstWeekDays.Name = "lstWeekDays";
this.lstWeekDays.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(263, 97);
this.lstWeekDays.TabIndex = 13;
this.lstWeekDays.Tag = "lstlstWeekDays";
this.lstWeekDays.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.lstWeekDays.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.SmallIcon;
this.lstWeekDays.Visible = false;

// Code behind

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.lstWeekDays.Items.Add("Monday");
    this.lstWeekDays.Items.Add("Tuesday");
    this.lstWeekDays.Items.Add("Wednesday");
    this.lstWeekDays.Items.Add("Thursday");
    this.lstWeekDays.Items.Add("Friday");
    this.lstWeekDays.Items.Add("Saturday");
    this.lstWeekDays.Items.Add("Sunday");
}

private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstWeekDays.Visible = true;
}

private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstWeekDays.Visible = false;
}
```

Add the checkboxes to this list instead of the panel.

Comment: Are you aware of the CheckedListBox control? I'm not suggesting you settle for anything you don't like but as a foundation control that does the same job - I think it's worth considering :P

Comment: I need it to be a dropdown :(

Comment: No problem. Can you please include the code you have at the moment? If we can reproduce the problem it will be easier to fix D:

Comment: Take a look at the link i posted. it's pretty much that. i just load the list differently

Comment: @Puzzle84 this kind of "issue" is from the custom control you are using, if you get it from another source (not customize it yourself), I don't think we can help you solve this problem. If you customize it yourself, you should post some code or better all the code of that control.

Comment: Updated code above. i don't see how you think this was ever a custom control.