# ComboBox with checkbox as dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, combobox

I am working in a winform application where I want to have a Combobox and it's dropdown should contain checkboxes like this:

[image]

These checkboxes are search conditions and I must be able to handle the check/Uncheck event of the checkboxes (at onetime i must be able to check/uncheck multiple checkboxes).

Any help or way to do !!!

Comment: From outisde; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

Comment: Hope you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822678/is-there-a-simple-way-to-implement-a-checked-combobox-in-winforms/8823170#8823170

Comment: @Uthistran, I already tried to use that but it is not working properly.l

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `ItemCheck` event.
It would look around these lines:

```
void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    //Code here
}
```

Additionally you can retrieve the state of the boxes like this `CheckState.Checked`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at this page here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

It shows how to implement a [CheckedListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_0) into a Combobox which should solve your problem.