# C# Winform how to allow panel draw outside the panel's parent?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a form that shows data and the filter that has checkbox in it

[combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdoY2.png)

I have used a Button and a Panel to do this and found that the panel is only shown in the parent's panel not float like the combobox

or panel can't do like this?

Regards

Comment: panels cant go outside of the forms bounds. A `ContextMenuStrip` may be able to if you're able to use that.

Comment: So why don't you use a Combobox? (Which btw internally creates a separate form)

Comment: The drop-down of the combobox is not a control itself.  You won't find it back in the toolbox, these kind of windows do not behave well at design-time since they'd "stick out" of the design surface as well.  They are top-level windows.  A ContextMenuStrip is a good example.  And the one you know, Form.   Making it look like it is glued to a control (like combobox) is easy to do, you use the Show(owner) overload so it is on top and subscribe the LocationChanged event of the owner to keep it glued.

Answer (score 1):

You want something that cannot be done with parented components (like panels) 
I see some options:

(1) owner draw a combobox to include checkboxes, see Codeprojects https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

or

(2) Create a small floating popup form without system menu and a single pixel border. Inside the form, you could place a CheckListBox docked Fill to allow for filter checkboxes for each item.. you may have a look at this topic [Is there a simple way to implement a Checked Combobox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822678/is-there-a-simple-way-to-implement-a-checked-combobox-in-winforms/8823170#8823170)

(3) Both solutions have drawbacks. Actually it may be better to avoid it, find another way to specify your filter options, redesign your UI.